# C#, Delete first row from gridview element

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This has been asked many times, but I can't seem to find a direct answer.

Using C#, I use a datatable to fill a gridview. The first row of my datatable contains the table headers, so I loop through that row and fill the gridview header row. But now I need to get rid of that first row (the header row) in the table. I've looked all over, and all sources agree that the correct syntax is:

```
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Station ID Request$]";
   OleDbDataAdapter adaBatch = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnExcel);
   DataTable dtBatch = new DataTable();
   adaBatch.Fill(dtBatch);
   gv_stations.DataSource = dtBatch;
   gv_stations.DataBind();
   //  Fill gridview headers with first row of data (spreadsheet headers)
   int i = 0;
   foreach (DataColumn col in dtBatch.Columns)
   {
       gv_stations.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = dtBatch.Rows[0][i].ToString();
       i++;
   }
   //  Remove the first line of the gridview (contains header info)
   gv_stations.DeleteRow(0);
```

Everything works but the last line, which gives me this error:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The GridView 'gv_stations' fired
event RowDeleting which wasn't handled. at
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDeleting(GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow row, Int32
rowIndex) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DeleteRow(Int32 rowIndex)
```

Every resource I've tried says that last line should be OK. Can anyone tell why I'm getting that error?

EDIT: Here is my gridview object, as requested.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_stations" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"    
    CssClass="c_gvv c_gvv_stations_results"
    style="white-space:nowrap;">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why are you adding a header row only to remove it?

Comment: Because I need that info to fill in the header rows.

Comment: So you want to fill the header row of the gridview, is that all you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I need to fill the gridview with the contents of the datatable. The first row of the the datatable contains the header info. So I need to get all rows, fill in the gridview header from the first row, then delete that row from the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read through your comments to other answers I'm a little confused as to what you're saying the problem is. Is it that if you simply bind to the gridview the first row in the data table (headers) appears as both the header row and the first row of data in the gridview?

It seems odd that if you don't want the header row that you first retrieve it and then go through the hassle of adding it all with your foreach loop only to then try and remove it.

If you don't want the header row selected in the first place you can amend your connection string (presumably strConnExcel?) to include "HDR=No", which will stop it from bringing back the first row in the first place.

However, if you want the header row then use "HDR=Yes" and simply bind to your gridview. It will know what the header row is. Looking at what you're doing though it looks like your trying to add the header row and then delete it!?

Comment: I want the first row of the data table to appear in the column headers. Then I need to get rid of it in the table itself. I don't understand "HDR=Yes"... what is that?

Comment: sr28, you solved my problem. I didn't understand the HDR propertiy, but I just searched for it, and yep, that was my problem. Most of my code was a workaround for something I didn't understand. Thanks.

Comment: @buckshot - no problem. Sometimes it's better to explain what the general goal is rather than the specific problem. That way people can suggest alternatives to your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to delete a row from `GridView` rather you should delete it from `DataTable`. Use this line:

```
dtBatch.Rows[0].Delete();
```

Instead of this:

```
gv_stations.DeleteRow(0);
```

You can also simply your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dtBatch.Columns.Count; i++)
    gv_stations.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = dtBatch.Rows[0][i].ToString();
```

**Complete code:**

```
...
//Fill gridview headers with first row of data (spreadsheet headers)
for(int i = 0; i < dtBatch.Columns.Count; i++)
    gv_stations.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = dtBatch.Rows[0][i].ToString();

//Remove the first line of the gridview (contains header info)
dtBatch.Rows[0].Delete();

//now do the bindings
gv_stations.DataSource = dtBatch;
gv_stations.DataBind();
```

Comment: Shaharyar, I need that first row because it contains my grid headers. Once the gridview is bound then I loop through the first row to name the column headers. At that point, removing the row from the datatable doesn't help me. I tried to remove the first row and then rebind the gridview, but the headers all refresh back to their default. Thanks for your reply, but that won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your edit with complete code - this was my original approach, but it doesn't work either. The loop that fills in the header row doesn't work on a gridview that hasn't been bound. I need to bind it first, then update the headers. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the GridView to a DataSource:

gv_stations.DataSource = dtBatch;
   gv_stations.DataBind();

Either remove it from the datasource and then databind, or databind and remove it from the gridview without redatabinding.

Or if you want to keep it there, You can make it invisible:

gv_stations.rows[0].visible=false

Comment: I have to bind it before I set the headers; and your suggestion, "remove it from the gridview without redatabinding." was what I was trying to do. However, your suggestion about making that row invisible worked like a charm, thanks much.